# Variable-sized Array Initialization in Java

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

I have an array of integers in Java that is initialized as follows:

```
public int MyNumbers[] = {0,0,0,0};
```

I would like to, however, initialize the array to a variable-length number of zeroes.

```
private int number_of_elements = 4;
public int MyNumbers[] = {0} * number_of_elements; // ????
```

I am clueless how to do this being new to Java coming from C. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

I know I could use a `for` loop, but I hoping there was a simple way to do it.

Comment: In Java `int[]` arrays are initialized with all elements 0 by default, so no other action needs to be taken except `new int[n]` to create an array filled with 0. ("[Then \[...\] a one-dimensional array is created of the specified length, and **each component of the array is initialized to its default value**.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.2) \[...\] [For type `int`, **the default value is zero**, that is, `0`.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)")

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
int[] myNumbers = new int[size];
Arrays.fill(myNumbers, 0);
```

see http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Comment: Thanks, dude! Am I right in assuming the import line is just `java.util.Arrays`?

Comment: Yup. One thing to note, though, is that according to the source of Arrays.java (JDK 6) the above function does indeed use a for loop. But one day it might just as easily change that behaviour to use something more low level such as a memset (through JNI).

Comment: I would trust the JVM to replace this code with faaaaaast code. Typically loops are unrolled by the JVM, mebbe her it even optimized it to a memset. In Java, never optimize at the code level!

Answer (score 6):

```
int[] MyNumbers = new int[number_of_elements];
```

Comment: I think the zero in the example code is meant as an example, while this one-liner will create the array filled with zeroes, it still doesn't enable the OP to fill it with another, arbitrary value.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively you could use [`ArrayList`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) so that you don't need to worry about the size beforehand. It will dynamically expand the internal array whenever needed.

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
numbers.add(0);
numbers.add(2);
// ...
```

[Here's a tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/index.html) to learn more about the Collections API, which `ArrayList` is part of.

Comment: +1 For use of ArrayList. That's exactly what I was thinking he should do.

Answer (score 2):

```
int[] MyNumbers = new int[number_of_elements];
```

Since this is an array of `int` the array elements will get the default value for int's in Java of `0` automatically.

If this were an array of `Integer` objects then you would have to fill array after creating it as the default value for an object reference is `null`. To set default values in an `Object` array you can do the following:

```
Integer[] MyNumbers = new Integer[number_of_elements];
java.util.Arrays.fill(MyNumbers, new Integer(0));
```

The same technique could of course be used to initialize the `int` array to values other than zero like so:

```
int[] MyNumbers = new int[number_of_elements];
java.util.Arrays.fill(MyNumbers, 1);
```

Comment: nitpick: when you fill the Integer array, you should probably use 'Integer.valueOf()' instead of 'new Integer()' since that will make use of the Integer cache (see http://tech.puredanger.com/2007/02/01/valueof/ for an interesting read)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something similiar to Memset in C, I don't think there is one. The Arrays.fill implementation seems to be the same as a for loop if you look at Javadoc.

However, I came across this article that discusses the same question
http://www.searchenginecaffe.com/2007/03/how-to-quickly-reset-value-of-java.html
It appears that using system.arraycopy is your better solution and this is the function you can use (copied from the link)

```
public static void bytefill(byte[] array, byte value) {
 int len = array.length;
 if (len > 0)
 array[0] = value;
  for (int i = 1; i < len; i += i) {
    System.arraycopy( array, 0, array, i, ((len - i) < i) ? (len - i) : i);
 }
}
```